# How to make express receives a query from a param

Tags: angularjs, express

I want to pass my query to my server and then express make it render with that query like "localhost:3000/myApp/items?search=myQuery
This is with angularjs, express and node.

**angular.service**

```
 export class ProductsService {
      constructor ($http) {
        'ngInject'
        this.$http = $http;
      }

      getProducts (query) {
        return this.$http.get(`myApp/api/items?q=${query}`).then((response) => response.data)
      }
    }
```

this is my **routes in express**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const product = require('./product-controller')

router.get('/items/q=:query', product.getProducts)

module.exports = router
```

**controller**

```
const ProductService = require('./product-service')

class ProductController {

  static async getProducts (req, res) {
    const query = req.params.query
    console.log(query)
    try {
      const ProductServiceInstance = new ProductService(req, res)
      const products = await ProductServiceInstance.getProducts(query)
      return res.render.json(products);
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw(err)
    }
  }
```

**service**

```
const axios = require('axios')

    class ProductService {

      async getProducts (query) {
        try {
          const url = 'https://api.zysn.com/sites/zys/search?q=' + query
          const response = await axios.get(url)
          return response.data.results
        }
        catch (err) {
          throw(err)
        }
      }

    }

    module.exports = ProductService
```

Comment: The route should just be `/items`, not `/items/q=:query`?

Comment: If I do that, the items landing gets rendered, But the query is undefined

Answer (score 0):

change the `$http.get` to the following syntax and I thinks you are good to go:

```
getProducts (query) {
        return this.$http.get(`myApp/api/items`, params: {q: query})
                   .then((response) => response.data)
}
```